# Merge a HTML tables cells if the row ids match?

Tags: javascript, html, database, html-table

I have a results set from my model, in my database I have patient data, each patient can have 1 result or many results, what I want to do is merge the first column in my results table if the pin matches, so for example If I have a patient who had 3 tests it currently looks like this:

```
PIN | Name | test ... etc 
1   | Alan | HIV .... 
1   | Alan | Chlamydia ... 
1   | Alan | Vit D ...
```

what id like it to look like is:

```
PIN | Name | test ... etc 
    | Alan | HIV .... 
1   | Alan | Chlamydia ... 
    | Alan | Vit D ...
```

Ive got the code that seperates the pins in my controller:

```
foreach ($results as $result){    
    if ($result['pin'] === $last_pin){
        $result['pin'] = null;
    } else {
        $last_pin = $result['pin'];
    }
}
```

This gives me the desired output in my view, for example:
`1, 2, 3, 4` instead of `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, etc`

But how do I go about making my table "Pretty"? do I use `colspan` or `rowspan`? I've never used them before and can't work it out!

Comment: You might structure your data array so that one pin can have several sub-arrays. That way you can count the entries for each pin and generate `rowspan` attributes accordingly. Can we see your actual `$results` and `<table>`?

Comment: Use flexbox instead of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) attribute lets you stretch a table cell over multiple rows. Rows that the stretched cell intrudes upon simply make room, as if the stretched cell were defined in your HTML in the appropriate place. For your use, this means the first row of a patient has one more cell than the others.

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>PIN</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">2101</td>
    <td>Alice</td>
    <td>The Mondays</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alice</td>
    <td>Corrugated Ankles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alice</td>
    <td>Slack Tongue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">4242</td>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>3rd Degree Sideburns</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>King Complex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to know how many rows a cell is going to extend through. You can collect that information in your PIN-separation code:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {    
  if ($result['pin'] === $last_pin) {
    $result['pin'] = null;
    $top_row['rowspan'] += 1;
  } else {
    $last_pin = $result['pin'];
    $top_row = $result;
    $top_row['rowspan'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Then skip creating the `<td>` element for the PIN if `$result['pin']` is `null`, and set the `rowspan` attribute to the value you saved.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for